# vlcj libvlc streaming desktop stops after sometime

Tags: java, streaming, libvlc, vlcj

I am trying to stream desktop using vlcj. But the streaming stops after `13` or `15` seconds.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc", WindowsRuntimeUtil.getVlcInstallDir());

String media = "screen://";

String [] options ={ ":sout =#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=56,fps=12,scale=0.5,width=176,height=144,acodec=mp4a,ab=24,channels=1,samplerate=44100} :rtp{sdp=rtsp://:5544/ok.mp4} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep"} ;  

System.out.println("Streaming '" + media + "' to '" + options + "'");

MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
final HeadlessMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newMediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.playMedia(media, options);
}
```

I was setting the `options` inorder to play the streaming in android 2.2 phones.

I am using 64bit OS Windows 7, 32bit vlc and 32 bit JVM.
I think the code is correct..

Can anybody give me a solution for this?

Is this a libvlc issue or vlcj issue??

Or problem for vlc with 64bit OS??

If there is any other solution to stream desktop for playing in android,help is appreciated

Please help me.

Comment: I was trying to set up desktop streaming server in PC.Becoz it does not continue after 15 seconds,i didn't manage to play that URL in android. In PC, i didn't get any error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem.

The problem is no more when i `removed` this line

```
NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("libvlc", WindowsRuntimeUtil.getVlcInstallDir());
```

I didn't understand how this got correct after removing this line.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing "mediaPlayerFactory " as a static variable

Here is an example: http://pastie.org/8094631